# How to force test a Firestore parallel Transaction?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Transactions are used for atomic changes and when two clients may change the same data at the same time.

I want to test in the dev env if my transaction is having its expected behavior when there is a parallel transaction running from multiple clients requests. It runs only in my Cloud Functions. I can't let any undesired behavior of this nature to happen in the prod env, so I want to check in dev if everything is alright when it happens, even being unlikely.

Is it possible to force this test case?

Using JS/TS.

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#ramping_up_traffic), you can implement parallel reads as you migrate traffic to a new collection, read from the old collection first. You can also watch this video, to [understand cloud functions in dealing with parallel executions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzTS6mFDGjU).

Comment: @RJC Hmm... as far as I can tell, it doesn't seems to be related to my question

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire transaction again. For example, if a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction. This feature ensures that the transaction runs on up-to-date and consistent data. Refer to this documentation regarding [updating data with transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions).

You can check this [post](https://medium.com/@arshadshaikh827/firestore-and-concurrent-read-write-transactions-in-working-146aa53862c9) that discusses concurrent read and write at the same time. Another [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#node.js) that also has an example on how to create and run a transaction using Node.js.

Lastly, you can consider creating two FirebaseApp instances, and running the same transaction in both and then synchronize between the two in the single process that they run in. Or, use testing tools that support parallel tests, like [Node TAP](https://node-tap.org/docs/api/parallel-tests/).